# How can you display a ComboBox's ValueMember as a string?

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to figure this out but I keep getting stuck.

I have a Microsoft Access database set up that has a set of descriptions of codes (my Display Member on the ComboBox), and code numbers as the Value Member on the ComboBox. I would like to select a description in the ComboBox and have the actual code number display as a label.

Every method I've been trying has been fruitless for me, can anyone shed some light on this and help me find a way to code this?

EDIT: As requested, here's something I've been trying.

I found this link in my search (http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic-net/7283/filling-and-getting-valuemember-combobox-vbnet.html), and upon trying out this method, I found difficulty in linking the sub procedure for filling the combobox with data coming from the database to the dim variables I wrote in the "Form1_Load" sub. The errors I was receiving were telling me that the variables were undefined, even though I defined them in the load of the form.

Comment: Perhaps if you show one ot these _fruitless_ methods you will find someone that fix your problem. As is this question is just a request to write code that could be hypothetical useful for you.

Comment: I posted an edit with requested information.

Comment: DisplayMember and ValueMember tell the control the property names to use from a DataSource which can be some sort of list or a DataTable. Hard to tell what you are doing with no code.

Comment: If you define variables in the form_load sub then you cannot access them later in other sub routines. You need to learn the scope of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Handle YourComboBox.SelectedValueChanged event. Retrieve value from  YourComboBox.SelectedValue property and use it as YourLabel.Text